# Installing java 5 in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ubuntu-11.04

i was trying to install java in ubuntu 11.04, i downloaded "jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin" for this i used the tutorial [this](http://flnkr.com/2012/02/18/installing-java-1-5-on-ubuntu-11-10/) and [this](http://possiblygonewrong.blogspot.in/2010/11/setting-up-tomcat-server-adapter-in.html)

```
# sudo mv jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin /usr/lib/jvm
# cd /usr/lib/jvm
# chmod +x jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin
# ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin
```

when i execute the command     `# ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin` i do get the following error messages

```
Do you agree to the above license terms? [yes or no] 
y
Unpacking...
./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin: 394: cannot create install.sfx.3350: Permission denied
Checksumming...
/usr/bin/sum: install.sfx.3350: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
chmod: cannot access `install.sfx.3350': No such file or directory
Extracting...
./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin: 424: ./install.sfx.3350: not found
mkdir: cannot create directory `jdk1.5.0_22/jre': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `jdk1.5.0_22/jre/.systemPrefs': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch `jdk1.5.0_22/jre/.systemPrefs/.system.lock': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `jdk1.5.0_22/jre/.systemPrefs/.system.lock': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch `jdk1.5.0_22/jre/.systemPrefs/.systemRootModFile': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `jdk1.5.0_22/jre/.systemPrefs/.systemRootModFile': No such file or directory
cd: 751: can't cd to jdk1.5.0_22
```

am new to ubuntu environment, am trying to setup eclipse with Java EE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `sudo ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin`, since you don't have write permission in that directory. However, `root` does.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your bin with super user permission `sudo`.
Also if you have newest version of JDK (I suppose you do) you can set compliance level of sources to 1.5

Answer (score 0):

You need permissions for it. You have two options, either switch into a super user mode, using:

`#su`

Though this method is not encouraged.
The second and the most common and appropriate method is to use `sudo` command,as:

`#sudo ./jdk-1_5_0_22-linux-i586.bin`